# Laravel Eloquent Advance Querying

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder, laravel-7, laravel-query-builder

I have 5 different tables as `projects, systems, attachments, tasks, users` on Laravel I haven't assign a relationship for each table what I am trying to do is linking each table using ID.

[image]

```
$objFetch = Task::addSelect(
            [
                'project_id' => Project::select('title')->whereColumn('project_id', 'projects.id'),
                'tester_id' => User::select('name')->whereColumn('tester_id', 'users.id'),
                'system_id' => System::select('name')->whereColumn('system_id', 'systems.id'),
                'assigned_id' => User::select('name')->whereColumn('assigned_id', 'users.id'),
            ],
        )->paginate(20);
```

This return the expected output as

```
       {
            "id": 1,
            "document_auto_id": 101,
            "document_type": null,
            "document_name": "Tasks",
            "file_name": "Task_394_1622175671_195.png",
            "file_extention": "png",
            "file_size": "105383",
            "note": null,
            "created_at": "2021-05-28T04:21:11.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-05-28T04:21:11.000000Z"
        },
```

> **Question** is there any solutions to get the attachments for each tasks?

**Laravel Eloquent** answer is highly appreciated instead of Query building

Comment: I don't see how the tables shared relates to the query shared or the result shown.

Comment: I find the values by each tables ID

Comment: I'm still not clear. There doesn't seem to be any sort of reference to system or project anywhere on the tables you shared.

Comment: @apokryfos, please check my answer. what i did was solve my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DB tables are often related to one another. therefore we can use table ID to get the output. the error occurs because I have not defined it on the Model. **THE PROBLEM WAS SOLVED AS I DO FOLLOWING STEPS**

**MODEL**

```
class Task extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'priority',
        'project_id',
        'system_id',
        'tester_id',
        'assigned_id',
        'description',
        'status',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'attachments' => 'array',
    ];

    public function Attachment()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Attachment::class, 'document_auto_id');
    }

    public function Project()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Project::class, 'id', 'project_id');
    }

    public function System()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(System::class, 'id', 'system_id');
    }
    public function assignedTo()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'id','assigned_id');
    }

    public function testerTo()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'id','tester_id');
    }
}
```

**FETCHING DATA WITH RELEVANT TABLES**

```
$objFetch1 = Task::with(
            'testerTo',
            'assignedTo',
            'System',
            'Project',
            'Attachment'
        )->get();
```